# Can anybody explain alpha filtering for delaunay implementation in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, convex-hull, delaunay

As [this](http://bl.ocks.org/gka/1552725) shows, you can use it to filter a delaunay triangulation and get a perfect limit.

Can anybody explain the magik algorithm?

Comment: The source would probably a good place to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Background

There isn't really much magic beyond classic [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) algorithm, which is implemented as function `d3.geom.delaunay()` within D3.

In the example you linked to, [alpha shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) are implemented as modified Delaunay triangulation, in such a way so that any triangle that has at least one side larger than `alpha` (in the example it has value `50`) is removed from triangulation.

That's why the result looks like this: (original vertexes, Delaunay triangulation, and Alpha shape)

[image]

### Details

`d3.geom.delaunay()` returns array of triangles, so this code:

```
mesh = d3.geom.delaunay(offset(vertices,600,0)).filter(function(t) {
    return dsq(t[0],t[1]) < asq && dsq(t[0],t[2]) < asq && dsq(t[1],t[2]) < asq;
});
```

together with fact that `asq` is `alpha` squared, and `dsq()` is function that computes squared distance between two points in the plane, causes removing any triangle with at least one side larger than `alpha`, which in turn produces the third image in the picture above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @VividD. mmm  The theoretycal explanation is very complicated for me and ...  In addition '50' is an arbitrary value, isn't it ? Would not it have more sense an angular value? Thanks anyway

Comment: The answer is right: d3.geom.delaunay() returns array of triangles, it is also reflected in the term "delaunay triangulation". So, the most logical way of removing something unneeded from a triangulation is to remove triangles. :) @Phpdna

Comment: Some of the sides of deleted triangles are shared with triangles that remain undeleted, so, yes, something will remain in the picture.

Comment: t[0], t[1], and t[2] are vertexes of the current triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha shapes is  when you remove any edges exceeding alpha from the delaunay triangulation. You can either use lines or disks to show alpha visually but the goal is to find a concave hull. Read here to find the concave hull:[Calculate bounding polygon of alpha shape from the Delaunay triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073170/calculate-bounding-polygon-of-alpha-shape-from-the-delaunay-triangulation/23073229#comment35336369_23073229).